# Firebase - uploading images when internet is offline

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase has great option of using their database and sending data to their db even if you are offline, and then when the connection is up again, it sends automatically the data to the db.

is it also possible to do it with the Firebase storage like send images even if the internet is off, and then when the internet is on again, it will send the images files automatically?

If so, how can I do it? If not with Firebase, any other option?

Comment: Yes. The Firebase Storage client supports resuming uploads. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts

Comment: What about in the other direction? In other words, there are pictures I want to **download** when online?

Comment: Did you manage to get a good solution? I am thinking to store the upload information in Firestore, and have a separate thread monitoring that to handle uploads.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. The Firebase Storage client supports resuming uploads. 
See the Firebase Storage documentation for uploads ([iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts)).

From there for Android:

```
uploadTask = mStorageRef.putFile(localFile);
sessionUri = uploadTask.getUploadSessionUri();
//save the sessionUri to persistent storage in case the process dies.
```

And then to resume:

```
//resume the upload task from where it left off when the process died.
//to do this, pass the sessionUri as the last parameter
uploadTask = mStorageRef.putFile(localFile,
                new StorageMetadata.Builder().build(), sessionUri);
```

#### Update (20160809)

One way to handle the sessionUri:

1. when you create the `uploadTask`, get the `sessionUri` and store it to the app's `SharedPreferences`.
2. when the `uploadTask` completes, remove the sessionUri from the app's `SharedPreferences`.
3. when the app restarts, check if there is a `sessionUri` in the `SharedPreferences`. If so: resume that upload.

Comment: thank you, two questions: `//save the sessionUri to persistent storage in case the process dies.` what does it mean? How do I do it? second question: `//resume the upload task from where it left off when the process died.` - how do I know if there a failed file waiting in this session? if there is, I need to call this uploadTask right when the activity creates? (onCreate())? thank you

Comment: I added a description of a possible way to implement this.

Comment: I can't just do `sessionUri = uploadTask.getUploadSessionUri();` I must do: `sessionUri = uploadTask.getSnapshot().getUploadSessionUri();`  otherwise it doesn't work. so when I do this, I always got a null pointer on sessionUri, even if I have an internet connection

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : Is it possible to upload file to firebase storage using 'sessionUri' while we are offline.  And firebase automatically upload that file to firebase storage when app goes online. Your solution works when we have already started upload.

Comment: The actual upload happens in a separate thread. But all callbacks are surfaced in the main thread, so they can manipulate the UI. If you're having problems making this work, open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am sorry, I was using `Google.await()` before my listener and this was not allowing my listeners to get registered. I removed it and now things are working fine. But I have one doubt now, if I try to resume the upload using uploadSessionUri, it does resume the upload but the `getDownloadUrl()` returned in `onSuccess()` is not a valid url. However, the file is completely fine as I see in the console. But the url is not valid.

Comment: @Arpit Patel :  I believe that while Frank's solution works if the upload is disrupted, you cannot actually get the "sessionUri" unless you had an online connection at somepoint. For Firebase Storage, there is no built in mechanism for holding onto that file in a local cache and keeping track of it.  That is only available for Firebase Database or FireStore.

Comment: I am not getting Sesson Uri when offline mode

Comment: @JeffPadgett Good point, a session results from having a connection to the Firebase storage instance! This feature would be really useful, and should be implemented sometime soon. Currently, I'm working on an offline SQLite based workaround to keep track of local files to be uploaded later... Are there any other alternatives you are aware of? :)

Comment: @varun, that's pretty much exactly what I did.  Except I actually stored the files' locations in shared preferences, because I was weird like that.  When online, check to see if there are any files stored in the SQLite or Shared Preferences database, then upload.

Comment: @JeffPadgett Oh, nice, thanks for the response. Good to know it works out as expected. By the way, aren't the file URLs from the firestore storage too long (about 160 characters)? Is there a way to save space on the firestore database?  :P

Comment: Hmm I guess that depends on how you are using them.  If you know the base url of your firestore storage docs, you could just save the ending part specifying the specific url since you already know the beginning part...  But I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @JeffPadgett Yep, you understood my question perfectly. Thanks! I'll look into that!

Comment: Is it possible to use `JobScheduler` to upload when the internet is reestablished?

Answer (score 6):

Technically, the accepted answer is incorrect given the OP question, which is,

> send images even if the internet is off

The accepted answer talks about resuming a download once started, which correct in detail but does not address the answer correctly.

The corrected answer is "no", you cannot upload an image to Firebase Storage if the device is not connected to the internet, the upload will fail and there is no auto-restart of the upload operation.

As previously noted, you must be connected to the internet, at lease long enough to start the upload and get an [uploadsessionuri](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/upload-state#uploadsessionuri) URI from Firebase.  Once the upload has started then you can resume the upload [using this sample code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts) or the code above.

As noted in the documentation, the resume URI is valid for about 7 days but it is the developer's responsibility to ensure that the file contents has not changed since the start of the upload.