# How to change maxUploadRetryTimeMillis from Firebase Storage Instance in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

When my Android device does not have any network connection my `FailureListener` only trigers after 10min like specified by Firebase when I try to upload a picture to my Firebase Storage.

I'd like to change this to about 10s with the `maxUploadRetryTimeMillis` property. But this does not work like intended.

My simplified code so far:

```
object StorageUtil {
    private val storageInstance: FirebaseStorage by lazy { FirebaseStorage.getInstance() }

    private val currentUserRef: StorageReference
        get() = storageInstance.reference
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: throw NullPointerException("UID is null."))

    fun uploadPicture(imageBytes: ByteArray,
                      onSuccess: (imagePath: String) -> Unit) {
        storageInstance.maxUploadRetryTimeMillis = 10000
        val ref = currentUserRef.child("pictures/${UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(imageBytes)}")

        val uploadTask = ref.putBytes(imageBytes)

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.i("Upload Failed", "This message never shows up")
        }
    }
```

`uploadPicture()` gets called like so:

```
StorageUtil.uploadPicture(picture) { url ->
                    moment.phtotoPaths.add(url)
                    renderImages()
}
```

This does not work. It trigers the `FailureListener` still only after 10min.

Hopy I get get some help from you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you you have change the `maxDownloadRetryTimeMills` too.

Especially if the device is offline already at the start of the upload. Because then it tries to fetch a upload URL which apparently counts as a Download.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to configure any timeout with the SDK.  The reason is because the SDK will silently and persistently retry and resume uploads when there is a bad network connection.  This is a very good feature for mobile apps.

If you need to move on to do other work after some amount of time, you'll need to set your own timer and trigger on the timeout you specify.  You can then cancel the upload and do whatever you need to do to recover.

Comment: My plan is to check this way if the upload is even possible mostly due to network timeouts. If not I'd save my state to a local DB and retry my upload asap when the connection is available again. Im referencing my idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495696/how-to-shorten-firebase-storage-download-retrying-period-on-network-error and here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(long)

Comment: Yes, you should definitely save state.  There is no telling how long it will take or if it will succeed in the end.

Comment: But if saving state with `SessionURI` is only possible if my upload initialy starts with network connection (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822982/firebase-uploading-images-when-internet-is-offline) 
And if I check for network connection in general from Android I only check for network not if Firebase Services are available or not. How would I go about this?

Comment: That's not how it works. You just kick off the upload and assume that it will eventually work when there is connectivity.  You can't "check for connectivity", as that is still not a guarantee that the app will *never* be able to connect, or *how long* will it take, or *if* it will be able to complete if you start the upload now.

Comment: Why do so many threads simply sugest to test internet connectivity with a ping call to say for example google.com before starting any network task then? Is this bad practise? I'd assume if I can ping google.com within a reasonable response time I should also be able to upload a <5mb File to Firebase Storage within those standart 10min. Is this a bad assumtion? If yes, how would I go about implementing my own timer for such a upload method like in my example above?

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption, unless you know for a fact the quality of the network of all your user at all times.  Ping is not going to tell you the whole story.  It doesn't give you a bandwidth estimate, just latency.  Try doing a web search first to learn about your options for making a timer on Android.

Comment: So my idea now is to save my data primarily to a local DB. Then I try to upload it with a async callback function (see edit). And if I did not get any result back yet I just retry at some later point manually. So there would be no need for a timer since FB Storage stops after 10min anyways and my upload function is non blocking. Does this seem alright?